# How to segue *without* storyboard between Master and Detail view?

Tags: swift, segue, master-detail, programmatically-created

I've create a Master-Detail project completely programmatically, that is to say there is no storyboard whatsoever (I deleted the files).

What I cannot figure out is how to segue between the Master View (MV) and the Detail View (DV)

I've tried

```
self.showViewController(detailViewController, sender: self)
```

and

```
self.showDetailViewController(detailViewController, sender: self)
```

from the MV, but it doesn't really work.

My MV's table is filled with cells which, when pressed, should zoom to an annotation on the mapView in my DV.

For some reason, the map on the DV and the table in the MV do not refresh after they load the first time when the app opens.

I'm using a custom object to pass the data between the views

MV:

```
    detailViewController.setRequired(self.customObject)

    self.showDetailViewController(detailViewController, sender: self)

    self.tableView.reloadData()
```

Where "setRequired" is a function that sets the DV's class variables to the updated values from the MV (this part, at least, works)

DV:

```
super.viewDidLoad()

    mapView = MKMapView()
    mapView.mapType = .Standard
    mapView.frame = view.frame
    mapView.delegate = self
    view.addSubview(mapView)

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.splitViewController?.displayModeButtonItem()
    self.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true

    populateMap(extractedObject)
```

where "populateMap" is a function that takes the object (the values are correct, no worries) and is meant to populate the map with the new information.

As I said, the mapView doesn't update, and the table doesn't either.

Any ideas?

(reminder, there is **no storyboard** file, on purpose of course)

Thanks in advance!

Jona

**EDIT**

Following vacawama's answer:

Yes, my masterViewController is embedded in a UINavigationController. in viewDidLoad of the MVC I have

```
let controllers = self.splitViewController!.viewControllers
self.detailViewController =  controllers[controllers.count-1].topViewController as DetailViewController},
```

but when I try self.navigationController.pushView... suggested, I get the following error:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

on the line `let controllers = ...`

**EDIT to the Edit**

Even after curing the found nil problem, the map and table just don't seem to upload. Any ideas?

Comment: You didn't mention SplitViewControllers before.  I gave you an answer for iPhone.  For the SplitViewController, both the Master and Detail are onscreen at the same time so no loading of new ViewControllers is necessary (which is what a segue does).  Just write the data you need to send to the detailViewController to a property or properties and then call a method to have the detailViewController to refresh it's view.  You could even do that automatically using `didSet` on a property in the detailVC.

Comment: Ok, thank you. This may be important: I have a button at the top of my MVC which opens a popover view once pressed. You select some things in this popover, and then press "update" - this should then use the selected information from the popover and update the MVC and DVC accordingly. Is there a specific way I should be moving from the popover back to the split view? Right now all I'm doing is self.dismissViewController(true, nil) at the end of the popover code. Thanks again

Comment: I think that is fine calling `self.dismissViewController` to dismiss the popover.  I assume that before you do that you send data back to the caller.

Comment: Yes I do, using let mcv = MasterViewController(), and then mvc.function name(data). **but**, still the map and table don't change. However, if I presentViewController(mvc), the correctly updated table pops up and covers the screen. So maybe I need something similar? Thanks again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Segues are a Storyboard creation.  If you don't have a Storyboard, you can't segue.  If your `masterViewController` is embedded in a `UINavigationController`, the programmatic way to move to the `detailViewController` is:

```
self.navigationController.pushViewController(detailViewController, animated: true)
```

If your `masterViewController` is not embedded in a `UINavigationController`, then you can present the `detailViewController` modally:

```
self.presentViewController(detailViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

---

**Update:**

In your updated question, you mentioned `SplitViewController`.
My initial answer gave you information for iPhone. For the SplitViewController, both the Master and Detail are onscreen at the same time so no loading of new ViewControllers is necessary (which is what a segue does). Just write the data you need to send to the `detailViewController` to a property or properties and then call a method to have the `detailViewController` to refresh it's view. You could even do that automatically using `didSet` on a property in the `detailViewController`.

Note, `viewDidLoad` will not run when you update the `detailViewController`.  You need to extract the code which updates the UI of the `detailViewController`.  Call it something like `updateUI`.  Then call `updateUI` from both `viewDidLoad` and when your data gets updated.  I suggest implementing `didSet` on your customData property and call `updateUI` from there.

Comment: Yes, thanks very much! I fell asleep, hence the delay